# Scrapy: Extract HTML as string inside Element

Tags: xpath, scrapy, css-selectors, lxml

I want to extract HTML inside a `dic`. For example in this piece of HTML:

```
<div id="main"><h1><xyz>Title<xyz></h1></div>
```

I want to extract div content: `<h1><xyz>Title<xyz></h1>` as a string.
Is that possible with CSS o Xpath scrapy selectors?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution with css selector is not possible, but pretty simple with xpath:

```
desired_str = selector.xpath("//div[@id='main']").extract()
```

Comment: `xpath("//div[@id='main']/text()").extract()`  for text content only: `Title`

Answer (score 1):

With XPath, use the dedicated function string() :

```
string(//div[@id='main']/h1/xyz)
```

Output : "Title"

EDIT : To output the whole path if you're looking for "Title" :

```
concat(concat("<",name(//*[.="Title"]/parent::*),">"),concat("<",name(//*[.="Title"]),">"),string(//*[.="Title"]),concat("</",name(//*[.="Title"]),">"),concat("</",name(//*[.="Title"]/parent::*),">"))
```

Output : `<H1><XYZ>Title</XYZ></H1>`

Comment: what I want is `<h1><xyz>Title<xyz></h1>`, not `Title`

Comment: OK. Post is edited with an ugly XPath 1.0 solution.